# Calling javascript function from parent window inside iframe but the iframe src is from remote machine

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

First i have this iframe from my page.

```
<iframe src="https://192.168.100.87/index.html">
   <p>Browser does not support iframe</p>
</iframe>
```

I have following script from my page head tag.

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function callMe(){
        alert('called');
       }
   </script>
</head>
```

And i have the following code from index.html from remote machine.

```
<body>
   <input type="button" value="Click" onClick="window.parent.callMe()" />
</body>
```

As you can see I'm calling my function of the main page where my iframe is included.
But unfortunately i can't call the function.

Is this possible, What am i missing here?
Thanks

Comment: have you tried it first.?

Comment: yeah. it's not working. :)

Comment: so that is your answer...lol.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access properties or call methods of windows at another domain. You can, however, use `postMessage` to send messages to frames at other domains (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage).

Try `parent.postMessage('testing', '*');`. The first parameter is the data to send; the second is the domain of the window you're going to send it to. Using `'*'` let's you send it to any host, but for better security, you should use the parent's actual domain.

Then in your parent page:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    if (event.data == 'testing') {
        callMe();
    }
});
```

This only works in modern browsers. If you need to support older browsers (like IE 7 or older), look for a postMessage polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the machine the code is being run is at 192.168.100.87 as well, this is not possible. You cannot access anything from a page of a different origin. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript